# Query in django based on a list

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a list for example:

```
home_type = ["villa", "apartment", "flat"]
```

And I want to query my objects in my database:

```
agencies = Agency.objects.filter(home_type_available__contains= home_type)
```

I think there is a problem with my query. I want to have all the Agency that contain at least one of the `home_type` in their `home_type_available`. 
`home_type_available` can look like that for example:

```
["apartment", "camping-car", "mobile-home"]
```

And if the `home_type` and `home_type_available` have at least one element in common I want to have this Agency.

This is my Agency model:

```
class Agency(AbstractUser):
    ....
    home_type_choices = (("apartment", "Apartment"), ("villa", "Villa"), ("camping", "Camping"), ("flat", "Flat") ... ("camping_car", "Camping-car"))
    home_type_available = MultiSelectField(choices= home_type_choices)
    AbstractUser.email = models.EmailField()
    ....
```

Comment: What is `Agency.home_type_available` actually ? Please post your models.

Comment: it's a list of home_type like: ["apartments", "camping-car", "mobile-home"]

Comment: A list ? You mean it's not a model field ???  __Please__ post your models code, else the guessing game might last forever.

Comment: @mel As bruno suggested, you should post your  **Agency** model for better resolution of your problem.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers

Done

Comment: Just what I feared. You have to fix this antipattern, cf my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MultiSelectField` is not a builtin field, but [from the doc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield), we can see that it "Stores to the database as a CharField of comma-separated values".

This is a terrible relational DB design antipattern, as it prevents you from performing simple, accurate and efficient queries on this field's content.

The right solution is to change your design to a pair of models (Agency and HomeType) with a [many to many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) (the link explains it all so I won't bother giving a concrete example).

I assume your project is still in development, so the correction and migration should be relatively easy. Believe me, doing it later (once it's in production) might be much more painful, and you **will** have to make that change anyway.

Answer (score 3):

In the place of **contains** you need **in** .Because contains compares field with strings but if you need to search a field in the list,then you should use:

```
your_list = ['1','2','3','4']
your_objects = Your_Model.objects.filter(field__in = your_list)
```

Use this as per your code:

```
home_type = ["villa", "apartment", "flat"]
agencies = Agency.objects.filter(home_type_available__in = home_type)
```

**EDIT:**

If home_type_available is a **MultiSelectField** field, then you need a complex logic to get the desired result.

```
agency_list = []
home_type = ["villa", "apartment", "flat"]
agencies = Agency.objects.all()

for agency in agencies :
    for item in agency.home_type_available :
        if item in home_type :
            agency_list.append(agency)

print agency_list
```

**agency_list** will contain a list of **Agency** model objects with atleast one home_type_available field in list **home_type**. Thanks.

Comment: The OP stated "all the Agency that contain at least one of the home_type in their home_type_available" - which hints there might be more than one value in "home_type_available". IOW as long as we don't see the models definitions, any answer is a wild guess.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yeah, it's entirely possible.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You were absolutely right. This type of knowledge comes from long experience. I am just a starter. Updating my answer.

Comment: This will still not work actually, cf the edited answer with the model's definition. The op would need a mix of "in" and "contains" lookups, which of course does not exist, and the solution is to fix the antipattern by using a proper relational schema with two models and a many to many relationship.

Comment: A bad solution is still bad, specially when the proper solution is well known and quite easy to implement. Using the right data structure (in this case relational schema) is key to effective, maintainable and efficient code. If your code is doing strange (and more complicated than they need to) things then your data structure is wrong. Fix the data structure first, and your code will become much simpler.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I completely agree with you. Updating the Db and Model structure is the most effective solution here. We just don't know the exact condition and motivation of OP's project.

Comment: Your solution is slightly wrong (you might get duplicate agencies) and would be a bit less inefficient using sets (yet still quite inefficient compared to a sql query though).